# How change component html template in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

For example I have this component with a simple template:

```
  <div>
    <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
  </div>
```

and I want to add this new template tag:

```html
  <div>
    <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
    <div class = "new-tag">
      </div>
  </div>
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: you just did it

Comment: I forgot, I want do this by something event, click for example

Comment: As I understand, you want to import another component in anothr component by css selector??

Comment: @KirillAchramionok I updated my answer. It was poorly formatted and didn't show the code. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a structural directive like `*ngIf`

```
  <div>
    <h2>Hello!!!</h2>
    <div *ngIf="showNew" class = "new-tag"></div>
    <button (click)="showNew = true">click me</button>
  </div>
```